# Access Slot Value in child component

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am passing treeselect component as a slot as below.

```
<template v-slot:filters>
  <treeselect v-model="value" :options="filterTreeData" />
</template>
```

My slot are placed as below.

```
<div class="rule-filter-container">
      <slot name="filters"></slot>
</div>
<div class="rule-operator-container">
  <el-select
    v-if="treeSelect.selectedValue.dataType !== dataType.Checkbox && treeSelect.selectedValue.dataType !== dataType.Radio"
    v-model="value"
    filterable
    placeholder="Type Or Select">
  </el-select>
</div>
```

As in above I have written v-if condition for the sake of example.

It is not working as of now. But I want to access treeSelect's selected value. and based on that I want to keep or remove "el-select" component.

So how do I access that selected value of treeselect in child component which is passed as a slot?

Comment: A slot can be used to expose something from a child component, in your code it does not seem like you are giving the slot anything. It is unclear which is the parent and which is the child. In general you would use the `scoped-slot` syntax to expose something from the child.
Check out the docs here:
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html
And a nice example here:
https://css-tricks.com/using-scoped-slots-in-vue-js-to-abstract-functionality/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to bind the slot's value to the component.

```
<template v-slot:filters :slotValue="value">
  <treeselect v-model="value" :options="filterTreeData" />
</template>
```

And in the component:

```
<div class="rule-filter-container">
      <slot name="filters"></slot>
</div>
<div class="rule-operator-container">
  <el-select
    v-if="slotValue !== dataType.Checkbox && slotValue !== dataType.Radio"
    v-model="value"
    filterable
    placeholder="Type Or Select">
  </el-select>
</div>
```

Comment: this is a nice work around, but there should be some way by vue through which we can access through slot.